# maven updates target jar even if code has not changed

Tags: java, maven, makefile

I'm building a jar package with Maven, and it seems like the jar file is updated on every `mvn package`, even if no sources were changed. The file size doesn't change, but modification date does.

This causes issues, as on a higher level there is `make install` which picks up the jar file with newer modification date and installs it again for no reason (leading to further annoyances like reloading in Tomcat).

Is this an expected behavior of Maven or am I possibly doing something wrong?

Comment: AFAIK this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Working as designed.

Comment: It's a surprising behavior for a build tool. Bottom line, it seems like I'd need something like a separate Makefile to track the java sources, which would allow to execute `mvn package` only if some source file really changed.

Comment: this does sound a bit strange as the jar plugin has a forceCreation option: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#forceCreation - this does not seem to be the default behaviour. Or are you using spring boot or something to create the jar? maven does not have such a close change tracking as gradle but it does monitor input / output file timestamps so this is a bit fishy.

Comment: I'm not using anything special, just `mvn -q -B package`

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. Based on the information you are running a `mvn package` and then sometimes afterwards a `mvn install` ? Is my assumption correct? If yes than you should know that `install` life cycle contains `package` which means in the second call you rerun the packaging parts etc. ?